# How to generate hash values from hash function and how to get integer values from these hash values?

Tags: bloom-filter, hash-function, cryptographic-hash-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL0dJ.png)
here,string is "SEAN",then it converted to bigrams, each bigram produce different hash values,but i don't understand which hash function is used here and how it generates int values from hash values to map in bloom filter.

Answer (score 0):

The hash function can be for example [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash), the diagram doesn't specify this. It doesn't matter which one is used exactly, as long as you always use the same algorithm when accessing the Bloom filter.

How to generate int values: for example using modulo the length of the Bloom filter bit array. A little bit faster is usually multiply & shift, but it is harder to understand.